# Combobox with scroll event

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a combox and I want to do somethings when we reach the end of the list while scrolling. I am not able to attach an event listener.

let's assume that we just have to print 'reached' in the console when we reach end of the list while scrolling.

How do we do this?

I came across few articles which said that Combobox does not expose the scollEvent.

Comment: Please provide details what language, framework, interface, code, error...use snippets

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.